# How to enable translate languages in magento2

Tags: magento2

How to show select language filter in frontend. 
languages likes en,fr and etc.

Comment: You have to install the language packages from any extension provider like mazaplaza

Comment: Already we have csv file, but my question is how to show the selectbox in frontstore

Answer (score 2):

You have to create Multiple store view as per your requirement.
For example:

- Website

  - Store

    - Indian Store View
    - French Store View

Set Locale Options for each store view.
Store switcher will be displayed.

Answer (score -1):

You need to select Countries from

> Admin > Stores > Configuration > General > Currency Setup > Allowed
>   Currencies.

Execute `php/bin magento cache:flush` command.

And you can see a currency dropdown in frontend.

Comment: Dhara Bhatti im asking how to show languages in fronend not currency

Comment: oh my mistake, thanks for realization. For that you need to use any extension.

Comment: We not using any extension